# Azure service principal - API permissions vs. AD Role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that needs to create AD groups and update their memberships via Graph API. I'll be using a service principal to do so.

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

- assigning the service principal to an Azure AD role (for example, "User Administrator": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#groups)
- adding API permissions to the service principal (for example, Microsoft Graph API's "Group.ReadWrite.All": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-by-task#groups)

What are the differences here? Do they both effectively give the same permissions?

Comment: Regardless if you use custom role or Graph permissions, giving the permission Group.ReadWrite.All or User Administrator to a service principal is really risky. 

When giving Graph permissions to an application instead of delegated, the application gets the full effect of the permission. Have full write permissions on groups opens up for elevation of privilege attacks as well as denial of service.

Comment: Are both required for operation to succeed OR can I go with either one  ?

Answer (score 0):

A built-in role is just a collection of permissions so your answer can be yes. If you grant the same permissions in as a built-in role then you will get the same effective permissions.  The "User Administrator" role has the following permissions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator

We created built-in roles to make it easier for users to quickly get role based access control in place.  If built-in roles don't meet your needs, you can always create a custom role.

Comment: `can be yes`  ? Do we need to do BOTH or just doing one will give the access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mulling over the same question - which approach is better, MS Graph permissions or built-in roles.  I'm leaning towards the built in roles for easier visibility and the potential to assign the permissions to groups.

Unless things have changed very recently you can only create AAD custom roles for a subset of "Application Administrator" permissions - not for any permissions.